# AWS Cloud EC2 server creating Automated backup of configuration files

Tags: aws

```
Automated backup of configuration files (15)
```

a.  The backup location will be /root
b.  The backup should be done weekly
i.  /etc/passwd
ii. /etc/group
iii.    /etc/fstab
iv. /etc/yum.repos.d (Directory)
v.  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg*

Comment: Please edit your entry to explain what the list of items marked `a.`, `b.`, `i.`, `ii.`, etc. are.  (requirements perhaps?)  Also please ask the question that prompted you to create this.  Is this something you need?  Is it a script you're dealing with and you're describing it's current actions?  What are you trying to say?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.